# vb.net easy way to resize Toolstrip in Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, toolstrip, menustrip

I have a main form with a `Menustrip` at the top and a `Toolstrip` at the bottom of the form. I like the `Toolstrip` to keep the same width as my form when I resize it. I read many posts about resizing items of the Toolstrip but not the `Toolstrip` itself.

Comment: ToolStrips are usually docked to Top, so resizing occurs automatically when the Form is resized. Did you set the `Dock` property to something else? Or did you add the ToolStrip to another container that doesn't resize?

Comment: @Jimi when I dock to Top the toolstrip is displayed at the top of the page, thats not what I want.

Comment: So, where are you planning to show a ToolStrip instead? The Bottom? Then Dock it to Bottom.

Comment: @jimi Thats what I did. The point is when I make the form bigger the Toolstrip doesnt stay connected to the left side of the main form

Comment: Did you set `[ToolStrip].Dock = DockStyle.Bottom` and it doesn't resize along with the Form? Then the ToolStrip is not directly parented to the Form, otherwise it couldn't do anything else but resize itself when the Form is resized. It's not really *a choice*. Check in the Document Outline Panel which Control is Parent of which.

Comment: Maybe because I am not using a ToolstripContainer?

Comment: There's no need for a ToolstripContainer. Do this thing: add a clean Form to your Project, the drop a ToolStrip from the ToolBox. What happens? What happens when you then change the `Dock` property value to `Bottom`?